# Windows 10 System Image(for backup)

Tags: windows-10, malware, bootable-media, system-restore, windows-system-image

Actually I have been wanting to create a full system image as backup for my Windows 10 PC as it has started giving troubles to me.
And I want **full system image as backup** as I don't want to reinstall my precious softwares.
So, my questions are :

1. Will making a system image on a new external hard disk will render it bootable ? Point being, will I still be able to use it for further storage purposes or not .I am gonna have to buy a new hard disk solely for this, so I need to know.
2. Suppose I make a system image of my windows 10 now. And my PC gets updated in future and say it was running on Windows 11 when it got crashed and I needeed my system image. So, when I restore, obviously it will be windows 10. Will I be able to update again to windows 11 ? ( I mean the same user, with the same IP address, updating twice to Windows 11. I hope that's not a problem for Microsoft. )
3. When I create a system image, do the viruses,malware etc. get copied too ? Will restoring a previous image to a clean PC can infect it ?

    
   **Thanks for helping in advance !**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Making a *System* Image does **not** back up data, nor other files. It only copies essential *Windows operating system (OS)* files.

1. A System Image is *not* bootable.
2. If you have a newer version of Windows OS, it might or *might not* accept reversion to an older version. If you *are* able to recert from Windows 11 to 10 from that file, you likely could update to Windows 11 again, *though you would likely need o install many updates*, before and after re-upgrading.
3. Though it is unlikely, it is *possible* that deepkly-hidden malware can be stored in the System Image.

**Much more useful is a full disk image.** That is, a copy, possibly compressed, of *all files* on your hard disk drive (HDD) or solid state drive (SSD), including your documents, photos, music, videos and all installed programs. These images can be browsed to find individual files, or the entire image can be restored -- often within 30 minutes.

There are a number of excellent, free and paid, programs to make a disk image, such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and [AOMEI Backupper](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html). You will need an external drive for the image with at least as much spaces as that actually used on your PC's drive.

As for malware, it likely will be in the image, too. Use reliable anti-malware applications to scan you machine before making any image, if you believe there are issues.

Comment: ! Thanks for the tip. I will surely go for a full disk image.BTW, I have a small question in mind. If it is not bootable, then how does it gets restored ? Do we just copy and paste ?  And further, does Microsoft not provide full disk imaging ? I mean,is it necessary to use a third party tool ?

Comment: Newer versions of MS Windows have an additional *Recovery* partition on the HDD, to allow for booting (sometimes!) if the main OS files are damaged.  See https://www.fonedog.com/data-recovery/windows-10-recovery-partition.html And, AFAIK, only third-party tools offer full disk imaging. In Linux, the native dd application can be used, but has no GUI. PowerShell allows *mounting* a disk image *after it is created*, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/mount-diskimage?view=windowsserver2019-ps , but I see no way to *make* such an image in PS.

Comment: "Making a System Image does not back up data" Really?

Answer (score 0):

*1. Will making a system image on a new external hard disk will render it bootable ? Point being, will I still be able to use it for further storage purposes or not. I am gonna have to buy a new hard disk solely for this, so I need to know.*

Generally, no.  You could *clone* your disk, which means you make a byte-for-byte copy.  That would be bootable.  But usually the term "system image" is understood to mean a non-bootable file - typically a compressed copy of your disk.  (Additionally, many imaging tools are smart enough to exclude things like the swap file, hibernation file, etc).

*2. Suppose I make a system image of my windows 10 now. And my PC gets updated in future and say it was running on Windows 11 when it got crashed and I needed my system image. So, when I restore, obviously it will be windows 10. Will I be able to update again to windows 11 ? (I mean the same user, with the same IP address, updating twice to Windows 11. I hope that's not a problem for Microsoft.)*

As long as you restore to the same hardware, you'll be fine.

*3. When I create a system image, do the viruses, malware etc. get copied too ? Will restoring a previous image to a clean PC can infect it?*

Yes.  Your system image contains everything on your hard drive - good and bad.